# dataframe to csv - csv file is not saving to local desktop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, databricks

I am using a script which creates a dataframe and then saves it as csv file on my desktop. When I run the code, i do not get any errors. However, it does not create any csv file in the location I speficied. I am using databricks for the coding.

```
from pandas import DataFrame

Cars = {'Brand': ['Honda Civic','Toyota Corolla','Ford Focus','Audi A4'],'Price': [22000,25000,27000,35000]}
df = DataFrame(Cars, columns= ['Brand', 'Price'])

export_csv = df.to_csv(r'C:\Users\myname\Desktop\export_test.csv', index = None, header=True) #Don't forget to add '.csv' at the end of the path
```

Comment: Did you try to use slashes `/` instead of backslashes? In python this is the correct path separator.

Comment: I tried and this is what I get:  [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: Then there is a typo anywhere in the path...

Comment: I don't know `databricks`, but perhaps you have code completion, i.e. you could try to type `c:/` and then `TAB`, then it should show you all directories in `C:`. Choose `Users`, then type next `/` and again `TAB` and so on. Go on like this to search your path from folder to folder...

Comment: Is there a directory `C:\Users\myname\Desktop` in your computer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to assign it to a new name (export_csv). The code below works well.

```
df.to_csv(r'C:\Users\myname\Desktop\export_test.csv', index = None, header=True)
```

Comment: I have a permission denied is it normal ?